# I am trying to install civicrm on my Mac and I got error in step no 5

Tags: installation, civicrm

[image]
I am trying to install CiviCRM on my laptop through Drupal 8.
please help me with this error.

Comment: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/ or http://civicrm.stackexchange.com may be more helpful than here.

Comment: also be more helpful to those who might try to help you by telling them more about what you have done. did you follow these instructions https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal8/

Answer (score 0):

This is simply that your version of PHP doesn't have the [intl extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) compiled in.

How you address this, very much depends on how you've installed PHP on your system or, if you haven't at all (and are using the built-in system PHP).

I'm just going to pick a generic route here, and assume this is OSX PHP as some versions don't come with intl support (e.g. PHP 7.3 shipped with macOS Catalina) and say ...  Save yourself some time and just use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to do this.  Follow the instructions to install `brew`, then install your required version of PHP using;

```
brew update
brew install php@7.3
brew link php@7.3
```

It likely already has intl support, you can test by using;

```
php -m | grep intl
```